# Jenkins webhook from gitlab - implementing different autobuild strategies

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

Note: I have webhooks working currently. This question is around design and implementation.

I am trying to design the process of using webhooks to trigger a build in Jenkins and specifically what process to use for doing release/qa builds.  I use artifactory for storing releases so ideally do not want to trigger release builds off a gitlab release as it means duplication of artifacts.

My initial thought was to have a webhook from tag for production build and then use a push regex'd to -qa for qa build.

My concern is around the -qa build in that if i need to merge multiple branches into a qa build that on initial creation and then merging each individual develop branch will cause a build.

Does anyone have any best practice on achieving the above? I do not want to hide the trigger by using something like having a comment with a specific word or phrase that is used in the commit.

Answer (score 0):

The gitlab API provides content in the post body of which two fields are 'before' and after' that contain guuids of whatever the trigger is.

For the tag you can check if the 'after' is not all zeroes then the tag is added and can act accordingly. If it is deleted then it will be all zeroes and you do not need to build.

For commits, I went with a push event off a wildcard of '*-qa'.  When a branch gets made or deleted this still throws events however there is a 'total_commits_count' field again in the post body that can be checked to help understand the action.  The 'after' field could still be used but for push events this felt more appropriate.